# Disabling Subscriptions

Tags: angular

I need to turn off subscriptions to not hang. Am I disconnecting subscriptions correctly? If  go to another page, the request will work, although the process component must be virtually inactive.

```
  ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.load();
    }, 1000);
  }

  load() {
    this._card.get().pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(card => {
      this.card = card;
    })
    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to auto-refresh your component? 
Then stop that auto-refresh once user navigates away?

Comment: @AnishKPillai Yes

Comment: Are you using SignalR? If not, what is the backed service that pushes the messages to Angular?

Comment: @AnishKPillai I don't understand what message you need to get out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below piece of code will unsubscribe the subscription & should also stop the timer. Hope this helps.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

ngUnsubscribe: Subscription;
interval;

ngOnInit() {
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  this.load();
 }, 1000);
}

load() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe = this._card.get().subscribe(card => {
      this.card = card;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 clearInterval(this.interval);
 this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
}
```